# Getting additional columns from sql

Tags: wp-query, sql

I have below function to get nearby posts, and what I want to achevie is to get additional custom meta out of table "rate_review" how can I achieve it?

```
function get_nearby_locations2( $lat, $lng, $distance ) {
       global $wpdb;

    $earth_radius = 6371;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT DISTINCT
            map_lat.post_id,
            p.post_title,
            p.ID,
            map_lat.meta_value as locLat,
            map_lng.meta_value as locLong,

             (
    6371 * ACOS(
      COS(RADIANS( %s )) * COS(RADIANS(map_lat.meta_value)) * COS(
        RADIANS(map_lng.meta_value) - RADIANS( %s )
      ) + SIN(RADIANS( %s )) * SIN(RADIANS(map_lat.meta_value))
    )
  ) AS distance



        FROM $wpdb->posts p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta map_lat ON p.ID = map_lat.post_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta map_lng ON p.ID = map_lng.post_id
        WHERE 1 = 1
        AND p.post_type = 'beaches'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND map_lat.meta_key = 'map_lat'
        AND map_lng.meta_key = 'map_lng'
        HAVING distance < '10'
        ORDER BY distance ASC",
        $lat,
        $lng,
        $lat
    );

    $nearbyLocations = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

    if ( $nearbyLocations ) {
        return $nearbyLocations;
    }
}
```

Which returns columns:

post_id
post_title
ID
locLat
locLong
distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add another join:

```
 INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta rate_review ON p.ID = rate_review.post_id
```

Add the condition to your where clause:

```
 AND rate_review.meta_key = 'rate_review'
```

Now you can add it to your `SELECT`:

```
 rate_review.meta_value AS rate_review
```

Comment: One more question. How to get this meta value in query without any additional call to database?

Comment: It's still one query with my solution, just one more join

Comment: I meant how to get meta or eg. 'distance' from this table in my query. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `distance` will be a property of each object of the result

Comment: Still cant get it out of there. Sorry to bother you, but could you please show how exactly would you call it?

Comment: Can you just `print_r( $nearbyLocations )` and see for yourself